# Linking CGICC in Eclipse using gnueabihf cross tool chain

Tags: c++, eclipse, cgi

I am using Ubuntu Linux, Eclipse Neon, and the arm-linux-gnueabihf tool chain to cross compile applications for the Raspberry Pi. Eclipse generally works well for this. I am usually able to cross compile and link the app, scp it to the RPi, and run it on the RPi.

I recently needed to add the CGICC library. I first installed the library on the Pi and then built a simple c++ app, built and ran it on the RPi without any issues. That says the library is properly installed on the RPi.

I then wanted to copy the library to the Linux machine so I could use it when developing on the Linux machine for apps to be run on the RPi. So I copied the following files from the RPi to the Linux machine:

/usr/include/cgicc folder from RPi to /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include on Linux machine. This copied 28 files from the RPi to a new CGICC folder located in /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include. The linux machine now should have all the include files.

/usr/lib/libcgicc*.* files (3 files) from RPi to /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib on Linux machine. The RPi also had 2 symlinks. I made the symlinks on the Linux machine. At this point is seems that the library has been migrated from the RPi to the Linux machine.

In Eclipse I created a simple project:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cgicc/CgiDefs.h>
#include <cgicc/Cgicc.h>
#include <cgicc/HTTPHTMLHeader.h>
#include <cgicc/HTMLClasses.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cgicc;

int main() {
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!

    Cgicc formData;
    form_iterator fChannel = formData.getElement("servochannel");

    if (fChannel != (*formData).end() && !fChannel->isEmpty()) {
        int channelNumber = atoi(fChannel->getValue().c_str());
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And I set the project properties as follows:
C/C++ Build/Settings/Cross G++ Compiler/Includes to /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include.
C/C++ Build/Settings/Cross G++ Linker/Libraries to cicc and library search path to /usr/arm-linux-gnueablihf/lib.

[image: Cross G++ Compiler Includes Settings]
[image: Gross G++ Linker Libraries Settings]

When I build a project, the project compiles but the linker throws two error messages:

undefined reference to `cgicc::Cgicc::getElement
undefined reference to`cgicc::FormEntry::getValue

It does not complain about the line in the source file "Cgicc formData;" but it does complain about every other line related to CGICC.

So what am I doing wrong? I've been fighting this for a week now, searching stack overflow and elsewhere. I hope someone here can help me. I'm getting tired of having to edit, build, and test on the RPi.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION FOUND!

The problem was that the libraries on the RPi were compiled with different version of the gcc compiler than was on the Eclipse machine. The RPi version could not be updated to the newer version on the Eclipse machine and visa versa. That meant that there is a possibility the interfaces between the compiled code and the library were incompatible, leading to the library problems I was experiencing.

The solution was to download the latest version of the cgicc library onto the Eclipse machine and build the library using the armhf cross compiler. This put the same versions of the library on both the RPi and the development machine.

Since cgicc uses Automake, the proper commands were as follows:

```
./configure CXX=arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ libdir=/usr/cgicc/lib includedir=/usr/cgicc/include 
make
sudo make install
```

Then Eclipse must be configured to look for the include and library files in the /usr/cgicc/include and /usr/cgicc/lib folders.

After that I was able to build my app, scp it to the /usr/lib/cgi-bin folder on the RPi, and run it.